# T-SQL Query Does not fill DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, t-sql

I have a `SQL` query I have to perform based on Operator Input.

I am building a form that has a Drop Down box that is populated with the table columns and a text box for them to provide the data.

The `SQL` statement was built using SQL Management Studio 2008. I have tested it (where `columnFilter="WorkOrder='100883'"`), and it returns 18 rows of data.

When I pass the same data to the method I wrote below, there is no error, the `SQL` is exactly the same as that I punched into Management Studio, but the `DataTable` never has any data in it.

The code could use a little cleaning up because I've been trying a few different things, but it is still logically valid ...just not the most *logical* at the moment.

**Please! Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?**

*I do not generally use the `AddWithValue` Parameter option (because I think it is sloppy and implies one does not know the data type), but in this case I do not know the data type (?). I suspect this method may have something to do with my problem, but I don't know how to check it.*

First, I'll show you the code:

```
public DataTable GetSheetMetalRequest(string columnFilter) {
  DataTable table = new DataTable();
  string sqlText = null;
  string[] split = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(columnFilter) ? columnFilter.Split('=') : new string[] { String.Empty };
  if (split.Length == 2) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT ");
    sb.Append("V.DateStamp, WorkOrder, PartNumber, Qty, EmployeeID, ");
    sb.Append("CAST(P.ProductionLineID AS VARCHAR(10))+': '+ProductionLine AS 'AcpLine', ");
    sb.Append("MTF, CAST(V.EventStatusID AS VARCHAR(10))+': '+[Status] AS 'AcpStatus', ");
    sb.Append("V.RequestID, ReasonID, E.DateStamp AS 'StartDate' ");
    sb.Append("FROM vwSheetMetalRequestByEvent V ");
    sb.Append("INNER JOIN ProductionLines P ON (V.ProductionLineID=P.ProductionLineID) ");
    sb.Append("INNER JOIN [Event] E ON (V.RequestID=E.RequestID) ");
    sb.Append("WHERE V.RequestID IS NOT NULL AND E.EventStatusID=1"); // EventStatusID=SheetMetalRequest
    sb.Append(string.Format(" AND [{0}]=@{0}", split[0]));
    sb.Append(" ORDER BY E.DateStamp, WorkOrder, PartNumber ");
    sqlText = sb.ToString();
  }
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlText)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, Conn_Tracker)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@{0}", split[0]), split[1]);
      string test = string.Format("{0}={1}", cmd.Parameters[0].ParameterName, cmd.Parameters[0].Value);
      Console.WriteLine(test); // ""
      try {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        if (table.Rows.Count < 1) {
          Console.WriteLine("no data");
        }
      } catch (Exception err) {
        LogError("GetSheetMetalRequest", err);
      } finally {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
      }
    }
  }
  return table;
}
```

Now, I'll show you what the SQL statement looks like (formatted to be pretty and readable):

```
declare @WorkOrder nvarchar(50)
set @WorkOrder='100883'

SELECT
  V.DateStamp, WorkOrder, PartNumber, Qty, EmployeeID, 
  CAST(P.ProductionLineID AS VARCHAR(10))+': '+ProductionLine AS 'AcpLine', 
  MTF, CAST(V.EventStatusID AS VARCHAR(10))+': '+[Status] AS 'AcpStatus', 
  V.RequestID, ReasonID, E.DateStamp AS 'StartDate' 
FROM vwSheetMetalRequestByEvent V 
  INNER JOIN ProductionLines P ON (V.ProductionLineID=P.ProductionLineID) 
  INNER JOIN [Event] E ON (V.RequestID=E.RequestID) 
WHERE
  V.RequestID IS NOT NULL AND 
  E.EventStatusID=1 AND 
  [WorkOrder]=@WorkOrder 
ORDER BY E.DateStamp, WorkOrder, PartNumber
```

Comment: What does split[1] contain? Is it a number or a string? So, for example, does cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@{0}", split[0]), Convert.ToString(split[1])); yield any different results? If it's a string, then does split[1] already have quotes in? You'll need to ditch those if it does.

Comment: I am confused as to where the "declare ... nvarchar(50)" and "set" words are coming from? I see the "test" variable, but it seems to read @WorkOrder=100883. Were these manually added?

Comment: @ron: apparently the first snippet is the ADO.NET part and the second is pure SQL in SSMS to test the query.

Comment: Use the [SQL-Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) to see what actually is arriving at SQL-Server.

Comment: @rontornambe: Tim is correct. The `declare ...` code is just a means to test the `SQL` in Management Studio.

Comment: @dash: If you'll refer to the SQL before the code segment, I wrote that `columnFilter="WorkOrder='100883'"`, so the string value `"WorkOrder='100883'"` would always yield `split[0]="WorkOrder"` and `split[1]="'100883'"`.

Comment: Just checking ;-) Try removing the single quotes. I suspect your parameter value is therefore @WorkOrder = '\'100883\'' - i.e. the literal string as it currently stands. You can quickly test this by trying cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@{0}", split[0]), "100883");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is apostrophe signs in split[1]. Database trying to find "'100883'" string instead "100883"

Please try this little hack:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@{0}", split[0]), split[1].Replace("'",""));
```

Comment: Since it's being passed as columnFilter="WorkOrder='100883' it's probably easier to just change it to columnFilter="WorkOrder=100883" ;-)

Comment: You rock, Radek! dash mentioned this in a comment, but it did not go to an answer.

Comment: Actually, my code physically places the `single-quote` into the string, so all I have to do is change my code not to do that anymore. QED.

Comment: Exactly! I like to let people find the answer themselves - it's more fun that way :-)